# How do I create multiple threads in Java Android Studio (for my specific application)?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, android-asynctask

I am working on an app in Android Studio using Java. When trying to run the app in the emulator, errors came up amounting to "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread".

I have done my best to research the problem, and the answer that I arrived at based on lots of research is that my Main Activity (and maybe other classes?) class needs to be performing certain operations on different threads. I have referred to here (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) and many other websites talking about various methods of starting new worker threads and then passing it off to the UI thread when there's an answer or result. I already am using AsyncTask in my application, but it doesn't seem to be enough.

I have a feeling the culprit is in my doInBackground method, which seems a bit long and includes the database connection. My question is, how do I use the methods described in the above link for Android developers (Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable), View.post(Runnable), or View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)) to make my doInBackground method operate on a separate thread?

Below you'll find my MainActivity. Please let me know if you need my other files.

```
package android.capstone.databaseconnection;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.test.R;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds

    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT=15000;
    private EditText etEmail;
    private EditText etPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get Reference to variables
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    }

    // Triggers when LOGIN Button clicked
    public void checkLogin(View arg0) {

        // Get text from email and passord field
        final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

        // Initialize  AsyncLogin() class with email and password
        new AsyncLogin().execute(email,password);

    }

    private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                // Enter URL address where your php file resides
                url = new URL("http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~gabschle/login.php");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }
            try {
                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                // setDoInput and setDoOutput method depict handling of both send and receive
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                // Append parameters to URL
                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                        .appendQueryParameter("username", params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter("password", params[1]);
                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

                // Open connection for sending data
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return(result.toString());

                }else{

                    return("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //this method will be running on UI thread

            pdLoading.dismiss();

            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            {
                /* Here launching another activity when login successful. If you persist login state
                use sharedPreferences of Android. and logout button to clear sharedPreferences.
                 */

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                MainActivity.this.finish();

            }else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){

                // If username and password does not match display a error message
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OOPs! Something went wrong. Connection Problem.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my LoginActivity.java class:

```
package android.capstone.databaseconnection;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.test.R;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse {

    EditText etUsername, etPassword;
    Button btnLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                HashMap postData = new HashMap();
                postData.put("btnLogin", "Login");
                postData.put("mobile", "android");
                postData.put("txtUsername", etUsername.getText().toString());
                postData.put("txtPassword", etPassword.getText().toString() );

                PostResponseAsyncTask loginTask =
                        new PostResponseAsyncTask(LoginActivity.this, postData);
                // use cgi.soic cgi-pub page here
                loginTask.execute("http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~gabschle/login.php");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(String output) {
        if(output.equals("success")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login Successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my AsyncResponse.java class:

```
package android.capstone.databaseconnection;

/**
 * Created by Gaby on 2/9/2017.
 */

public interface AsyncResponse {
        void processFinish(String output);
}
```

Here is my PostResponseAsyncTask.java class:

```
package android.capstone.databaseconnection;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class PostResponseAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private AsyncResponse delegate;
    private Context context;
    private HashMap<String, String> postData =
            new HashMap<String, String>();
    private String loadingMessage = "Loading...";


    //Constructor
    public PostResponseAsyncTask(AsyncResponse delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.context = (Context)delegate;
    }

    public PostResponseAsyncTask(AsyncResponse delegate,
                                 HashMap<String, String> postData){

        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.context = (Context)delegate;
        this.postData = postData;
    }

    public PostResponseAsyncTask(AsyncResponse delegate, String loadingMessage){
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.context = (Context)delegate;
        this.loadingMessage = loadingMessage;
    }

    public PostResponseAsyncTask(AsyncResponse delegate,
            HashMap<String, String> postData, String loadingMessage){

        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.context = (Context)delegate;
        this.postData = postData;
        this.loadingMessage = loadingMessage;
    }
    //End Constructor

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage(loadingMessage);
        progressDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }//onPreExecute

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls){

        String result = "";

        for(int i = 0; i <= 0; i++){

            result = invokePost(urls[i], postData);
        }

        return result;
    }//doInBackground

    private String invokePost(String requestURL, HashMap<String,
            String>postDataParams) {
        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response+=line;
                }
            }
            else {
                response="";

                Log.i("PostResponseAsyncTask", responseCode + "");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }//invokePost

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }//getPostDataString

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        result = result.trim();

        delegate.processFinish(result);
    }//onPostExecute

    //Setter and Getter
    public String getLoadingMessage() {
        return loadingMessage;
    }

    public void setLoadingMessage(String loadingMessage) {
        this.loadingMessage = loadingMessage;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getPostData() {
        return postData;
    }

    public void setPostData(HashMap<String, String> postData) {
        this.postData = postData;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public AsyncResponse getDelegate() {
        return delegate;
    }

    //End Setter & Getter
}
```

Comment: doInBackground() is already running in its own thread (that is the point of the AsyncTask) so it shouldn't cause that message. It also doesn't seem like you are doing a lot in the UI thread so not sure why you get that message. Is this all the code for the activity?

Comment: @MobileDeveloper Thanks for your timely response! It's much appreciated! I've included the rest of my Java classes above. Perhaps there is a UI thread blockage in another one of my classes?